# How to create a line graph from csv data?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I store some data in a csv file which I would like to graph in Blender. I would like to make a smooth line graph out of it.

What I'm doing right now, is read the csv data with python and store it in a cube's vertex data (on which I've generated enough vertex points to store it all). This is done using geometry nodes. I can then use Instance on points to fill every point with a sphere, and give it the correct coordinates.

I would like to do the same but with a line graph (using a curve), yet it doesn't work. If I create a curve in Geometry Nodes, it ignores the data I pass it from the Named attribute node. Probably because that data exists in the original mesh, but not on the curve. I've looked everywhere and find no solution.

My question is: How can one procedurally create a line graph to represent csv data?

Comment: if Crantisz solution doesn't work, pls provide blend file because we really don't know what exactly you did and Blender is often just about the details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same order of vertices in the curve and mesh, you can use Sample Index to pass data from one geometry to another:

[image]

Comment: Oh god, I was doing exactly this, with the minor exception of not passing the Index field to the Sample Index node (and it of course wasn't working). I have been going crazy for hours; this solves it, thanks.